# G++ cannot deduce result type of a generic function

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, g++, decorator

I am trying to write a method decorator `timing` that I intend to use as follows:

```
auto res = timing(my_func, arg1, arg2);
```

where `res` contains the result of `my_func(arg1, arg2)`.

My implementation of `timing` looks like this:

```
template <typename FunctionT, typename ...ArgT, typename ResultT>
ResultT timing(FunctionT fn, ArgT... args) {
    // do something here
    ResultT result = fn(args...);
    // do something else here
    return result;
}
```

However, this doesn't compile because G++ cannot deduct `ResultT` of the above call, for example the following minimal NOT working example:

```
#include <iostream>

// put timing method here

float my_func(float f, float g) {
    return f + g;
}

int main() {
    auto res = timing(my_func, 0.f, 3.f);
    std::cout << "Result is: " << res;
}
```

throws the following compiler error when compiled with `g++ test.cpp`:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:19:22: error: no matching function for call to ‘timing(float (&)(float, float), float, float)’
   19 |     auto res = timing(my_func, 0.f, 3.f);
      |                ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:5:9: note: candidate: ‘template<class FunctionT, class ... ArgT, class ResultT> ResultT timing(FunctionT, ArgT ...)’
    5 | ResultT timing(FunctionT fn, ArgT... args) {
      |         ^~~~~~
test.cpp:5:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:19:22: note:   couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘ResultT’
   19 |     auto res = timing(my_func, 0.f, 3.f);
      |                ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Why cannot g++ deduce the template parameter `ResultT`, shouldn't it be given by the function `my_func`?

Besides, when I specifically provide the value of `ResultT`, it works:

```
template <typename ResultT, typename FunctionT, typename ...ArgT>
ResultT timing(FunctionT fn, ArgT... args) {
    // as before
}

int main() {
    auto res = timing<float>(my_func, 0.f, 3.f);
}
```

Is there a way to compile this without explicitly mentioning the return value of my function? In fact, the function(s) I intend to use this method with do have pretty lengthy type definitions.

Comment: Function matching happens by argument types, `ResultT` is not deduced from the arguments, the function body is not instantiated to deduce a return type. Return `auto` instead of `ResultT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just use `auto` as your return type:

```
template <typename F, typename ...Args>
auto timing(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
    auto result = std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    return result;
}
```

If for some reason you feel truly compelled to name the type, you could also do this:

```
template <typename F, typename ...Args>
std::invoke_result_t<F, Args...> timing(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
    std::invoke_result_t<F, Args...> result = std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that one can use `auto` as a return type! Nice, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by making the first parameter `fn` to be a *function pointer* with the return type `ResultT` as shown below. Basically we need to make sure that `ResultT` can be deduced from the passed argument.

```
template <typename ...ArgT, typename ResultT>
//-------------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv------------------->fn is a function pointer
ResultT timing(ResultT (*fn)(ArgT...), ArgT... args) { 
   
    ResultT result = fn(args...);
  
    return result;
}
int main() {
    auto res = timing(my_func, 0.f, 3.f); //works now
    std::cout << "Result is: " << res;
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/b77K5nsKE)